# How to access non public metrics using tweepy v2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

As part of Twitter v2, there are public and non public metrics. As part of the non public metrics, there is the abiliy to check the amount of Impressions that a tweet got (The number of times it appeared on a screen), I have been able to access the public metrics, but unable to access the non public metrics so I could see the number of Impressions.

To access the public metrics I am using this bit of code:

```
tweet = client.get_tweet(id = tweet_id,tweet_fields=['created_at', 'public_metrics', 'lang', 'author_id'],expansions=['author_id']) tweetmetrics = tweet.data['public_metrics'] print(tweetmetrics)
```

How do I get the non-public_metrics?

Comment: You can only get non-public metrics for Tweets that belong to the account you’re authenticated as. You can use the account token and secret with OAuth 1.0A - this will not work with an app-only bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those metrics only for your own tweets. You can see in
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html
organic_metrics and  non_public_metrics Requires user context authentication.